# What is this door lock hardware part called?

Tags: front-door

We have Baldwin Prestige series front door entry handset. While removing the handle from the door to refinish the door, the screws broke off inside this little mechanism. Does anybody know what this is called? I have searched endlessly online for the part and cannot find it anywhere. I might have better luck if I know the name of the part. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour]. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Comment: I second the "screw extraction" option. Unless it's a really expensive lockset, replacement may be more time efficient.

Answer (score 1):

It’s called a “door lock rose” or “door lock rosette”. You can Google it or contact a door hardware supplier.

I’ve had excellent service from Emtek.com. Terrible website, but great customer service.